# How to call a stored procedure in spring using SimpleJdbcDaoSupport?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I have a stored procedure in my DB with one input parameter and one output parameter..

How to call this procedure in my java file using SimpleJdbcDaoSupport??

I'm a newbie to Spring.. Can someone suggest something for this ??

Answer (score 1):

[`getJdbcTemplate().call(..)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#call%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreator,%20java.util.List%29) looks like the method to use.

Comment: In the creator you should return a callable statement. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html?is-external=true for how to use it. it is plain jdbc